# Cannot read property 'ClearCredentials' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs an i'm trying to create a login form but i'm getting following error :

Cannot read property 'ClearCredentials' of undefined.

I have used some tutorial stuff. But now i started to create an application from scratch. But i'm stuck with the **AuthenticationService.js**

This is what i have done

app.js

```
(function(angular) {
    angular.module("app.directives", []);
    angular.module("app.AuthenticationService", []);
    angular.module("app.controllers", []);
    angular.module("app", ['ngRoute','ngResource','routes','app.directives','app.controllers',"app.AuthenticationService"]);
}(angular));
```

controller.js

```
//LoginController
(function (angular) {

var LoginController = function($scope,$location,AuthenticationService){

   var vm = this;

   //todo vm.login = login;

    (function initController() {
        // reset login status
        // calling function from AuthenticationService
      AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    })();


   /*  TODO: This has not been tested yet
    function login(){
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        // constructor from AuthenticationService
       AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username,vm.password, function(response){
            //Check if method respons === success
            if (response.success) {
                // calling function from AuthenticationService
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                // use function from FlashService
               // FlashService.Error(response.message);
               // vm.dataLoading =false;
            }

        });
    }*/

}

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope','$location'];
angular.module("app.controllers").controller("LoginController", LoginController);

}(angular));
```

AuthenticationService.js

```
(function (angular) {


    var AuthenticationService = function($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, UserService) {
        var service = {};

        service.ClearCredentials = ClearCredentials;




        function ClearCredentials() {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
        }
     return service;
    }



    AuthenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'UserService'];
    angular.module("app.AuthenticationService").factory("AuthenticationService", AuthenticationService);

})(angular);
```

If you have suggestions for this code please let me also know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inject two parameters:

```
LoginController.$inject = ['$scope','$location'];
```

But then you refer to the third one. Isn't this a problem?

Check if the inline version would work:

```
angular.module("app.controllers").controller("LoginController", funtion($scope,$location,AuthenticationService){
...
}
```

If it does, then there is an issue with Angular injection.

Comment: Great i got it working it was indeed  Angular injection issue. I added AuthenticationService and it works fine now.